# Mongoose Populate with Express, not working in production (Heroku)

Tags: mongodb, heroku, populate

This is a MERN app, hosted on github, and it works **perfectly** on localhost. Unfortunately, it does not work on Heroku.

The issue is the API request, it must return an object and populate an array of OIDs (see Department Model). API request is working. I'm getting the data from MLab, but it **doesn't** **populate**... instead returns: `"surveys":[]`

**API File**

```
router.get('/department_data/:d_oid', function(req, res) {
     Department.findOne({_id: req.params.d_oid}).populate("surveys").exec(function(err,doc){
          if(err) throw(err)
          res.send(doc)
     })
});
```

**Department Model**

```
**Department Model**
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create the survey schema
var departmentSchema = new Schema({

  department_name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },

  surveys: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Surveys'
  }],

  participants: [{
    type: String
  }],

  create_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },

  created_by: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Created_By'
  },
});

departmentSchema.index({ department_name: 1, created_by: 1}, {unique: true});

const Department = mongoose.model('Departments', departmentSchema);

module.exports = Department;
```

**Survey Model**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create the survey schema
var surveySchema = new Schema({

  survey_name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },

  questions: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Questions'
  }],

  created_date: {
     type: Date,
     default: Date.now
  }
});

const Survey = mongoose.model('Surveys', surveySchema);

module.exports = Survey;
```

Comment: try this const Survey = mongoose.model('Surveys', surveySchema, 'surveys'');
here 1st param is name of model you defined or want, 2nd one is schema, 3rd one is collection_name

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, it didn't work. Is the collection_name supposed to match key 'ref' in the model?

Comment: yes, you can do "ref" using collection name also. Like
surveys: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'surveys'
  }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

The problem was in the database: the ref OIDs got scrambled with a previous update, so when it was trying to populate, Mongoose couldn't find any matching OIDs.

**Solution:** we had to purge and re-seed. When the correct OID references exist, this code works as expected in localhost & Heroku.

Comment: How do you purge?

Comment: @daCoda - We are using **mLab**, so I logged into the dashboard and deleted the collections in question.

Comment: And that solved the issue? - I use mLab too... and have even deleted the whole DB and made a new one. Still can't populate() :(

Comment: I posted a response to your question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274545/mongoose-mlab-is-not-populating-populate-on-production-heroku).