# Mongoose is not populating (.populate()) on Production (Heroku), but works on Local

Tags: javascript, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mlab

Essentially I am having one of those moments. My app's on Heroku, and the DB it uses is mLab (MongoDB).

- It works on local (Cloud9), but not on production (Heroku).
- I can't get **.populate()** to work on production.

Do you see any gaps in my code below (snippet) that may cause Heroku to fail, while it works on local?

Thank you.

(I have tried purging the DB (deleting the DB and making a new one. Also I've for similar questions on this site. Also I have tried '**heroku local --tail**' command to debug and ran it on my local machine; it works on local... Just not on Heroku; appears buggy.)

```
 People.find(id).populate("friends").exec(function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log("! Error retrieving user. " + err);
            reject ("! Error retrieving user. " + err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("0! Friends should be populated: " + user);
            resolve(user);
        }
    });
```

My model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    friends: [    
        {
            id: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Person"
            },
            name: String
        }
    ],
    username: String,
    password: String,
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);
```

Comment: Anyone? Question not clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

Your API function looks ok.

I suspect your issue is with how your models are setup, or what is in your data-base. I had similar issues the first time I tried to use Heroku, because Localhost is more forgiving.

In order for your API to work, the following 3 things must be setup:

```
(1) Model file: people.js
```

must look like something like:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var peopleSchema = new Schema({

  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },

  friends: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Friends"
  }]
});

const People = mongoose.model('Peoples', peopleSchema);

module.exports = People;
```

And then you must have a 'Friends' model, that 'People' is referencing.

```
(2) Model file: friends.js
```

must look something like:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create the Comment schema
var friendsSchema = new Schema({

  friend_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
});

const Friends = mongoose.model('Friends', friendsSchema);

module.exports = Friends;
```

And lastly, in order for .Populate to work, you need at least two docs in the database.

```
(3) Database must contain a Person doc and a Friend doc
```

must look something like:

```
people.js : 
    "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bef3480f202a8000984b3c5"
    }, 
    "name": "Monica Geller"
    "friends": [
        {
            "$oid": "5bef3480f202a8000984b5b4"
        }
    ]

friends.js :
    "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bef3480f202a8000984b5b4"
    },
    "friend_name": "Rachel Green"
```

Hopefully this helps, or gets you closer to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was a version issue.

Had to ensure that all platforms (mLab, and my local database) were using the same version of Mongoose.

```
npm install mongoose@5.4.8 --save
```